# How to output pure JSON with no warnings in openshift's `oc ... -o json` command

Tags: openshift

When I output as JSON when using the openshift `oc` command, it also outputs warnings to stdout.

How can I output only the JSON so it can be parsed correctly?

For an example, the [corresponding github issue](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/23588) has example: `oc new-app $(git remote get-url origin) --dry-run --context-dir my-dir --name mw -o json > my.json` which results in Line 1 of the JSON file having: `warning: Cannot check if git requires authentication`. This is not valid JSON.

Comment: It is trying to access the Git repo to work out how it should build it. If a docker type build, try using ``--strategy docker`` option. If an S2I build, try using ``--strategy source`` and ``--image-stream s2iimagename``. By being explicit, it may skip the checks to try and work it out and just do as you tell it to. If that still doesn't work, use the ``--code`` option where Git url is argument, or if S2I use form ``s2iimagestream~giturl``. Sometimes these options behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is print all lines after the opening JSON bracket is found:

`oc ... -o json | sed -n '/{/,$p'`

This will trim the error and warning lines printed at the start, if any.